# Evaluate the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \big(\frac{1}{36k^2-1}+\frac{2}{(36k^2-1)^2}\big)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fourier-series

I have to evaluate the series:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{36k^2-1}+\frac{2}{(36k^2-1)^2}\right).$$

I tried using the identity $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ but I got stuck.

Comment: Did you try partial fractions?

Comment: Hint: $36k^2-1=(6k+1)(6k-1)$

Comment: @Nikunj The sequence in the problem converges to an irrational number, notably $\frac{\pi^2-9}{18}$. So partial fractions are unlikely to help very much, I think.

Comment: $\frac{1}{36k^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{(6k+1)-(6k-1)}{(6k+1)(6k-1)}$

Comment: @Nikunj They don't cancel each other out.. what are you suggesting?

Comment: @MXYMXY I see now, my mistake!

Comment: @Nikunj Indeed.If you just want to know the answer, see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty+(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B36k%5E2-1%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B(36k%5E2-1)%5E2%7D). But this hardly answers the OP's question.

Comment: Yes, looking at the answer, I wonder if we can make the expression as $$\frac{1}{3}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2} -\text{Some telescopic series giving $\frac{1}{2}$}$$, We'll get the answer lol.

Comment: Write $$1=\dfrac{6k+1-(6k-1)}2$$ and $$2=\dfrac{\{6k+1-(6k-1)\}^2}2$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee you are right.I got the answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A more general approach, proving the identity:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k^2+x^2}{(k^2-x^2)^2}=-\frac{1}{2x^2}+\frac{\pi^2}{2\sin^2(\pi x)}\tag{1}$$
for any $x\in(-1,1)$ is to check that both the LHS and the RHS of $(1)$ are meromorphic functions with the same-behaving singularities at any $x\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$. For instance, $(1)$ is just a consequence of:
$$ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(z-n)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}\tag{2} $$
since $\frac{1}{(k-x)^2}+\frac{1}{(k+x)^2} = 2\cdot\frac{k^2+x^2}{(k^2-x^2)^2}$. $(2)$ can be seen as a consequence of the reflection formula for the $\Gamma$ function, too, since:
$$ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(z-n)^2}= \psi'(-z)+\psi'(1+z). \tag{3}$$
If we plug $x=\frac{1}{6}$ in $(1)$, we get:

> $$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{36k^2+1}{(36k^2-1)^2} = \color{red}{\frac{\pi^2-9}{18}}\tag{4} $$

and it is possible to derive such identity also through Fourier-analytic methods.

Still another way is to notice that our series is just $\frac{1}{2}\cdot L(\chi,2)$ where $\chi$ is the principal Dirichlet character $\!\!\pmod{6}$, hence our series depends on $\text{Li}_2$ evaluated at the sixth roots of unity.

---

An elementary proof of $(4)$ comes from the inclusion-exclusion principle:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{(6k+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(6k+5)^2}\right) = \sum_{\substack{n\geq 1 \\ 2\nmid n \\ 3\nmid n}}\frac{1}{n^2} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{\substack{n\geq 1 \\ 2\mid n}}\frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{\substack{n\geq 1 \\ 3\mid n}}\frac{1}{n^2}+\sum_{\substack{n\geq 1 \\ 6\mid n}}\frac{1}{n^2}$$
gives:

> $$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{(6k+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(6k+5)^2}\right) = \left(1-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{36}\right) = \frac{2}{3}\cdot\zeta(2) = \color{red}{\frac{\pi^2}{9}}. \tag{5}$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on the statement - "Still another way is to notice that our series is just $\frac{1}{2}\cdot L(\chi,2)$ where $\chi$ is the principal Dirichlet character $\!\!\pmod{6}$, hence our series depends on $\text{Li}_2$ evaluated at the sixth roots of unity." Thank you.